# Multiply textbox.text by combobox.text and display the result into a textbox.text

Tags: c#, vb.net, events, combobox, textbox

I'm trying to do this while I'm wheeling a combobox.

The idea is to modify the TextBoxTotal.text each time I'm changing the ComboBoxUnit.text (new texboxtotal.text should be equal to texboxqty * comboboxcostunit)

But for some reason, it's not working... It's working with the "previous" cost.

Here is the code :

```
Private Sub ComboBoxUnits_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBoxUnits.SelectedIndexChanged
        Try    
            TextBoxTotalCost.Text = (Decimal.Parse(TextBoxQuantityUnits.Text) * Decimal.Parse(ComboBoxCostUnits.Text))

        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    End Sub
```

[Here is a short clip of the result (see the late TextBoxTotalCost.text...)](https://streamable.com/43x78k)
As you can see, the TextBoxTotalCost.text is one mousewheel late. Always. Annoying.

**EDIT 1**

The Combobox complete code

```
Private Sub ComboBoxUnits_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBoxUnits.SelectedIndexChanged

        Try
            TextBoxTotalCost.Text = (Decimal.Parse(TextBoxQuantityUnits.Text) * Decimal.Parse(ComboBoxCostUnits.Text))

            ComboBoxQualityUnits.Text = GetStringFromQuery("SELECT qualité_unité FROM liste1 Where Nom_Unité = '" & ComboBoxUnits.Text & "'")


        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try


    End Sub
```

Comment: Is this really related to the <sql> _language_?

Comment: Well, the comboboxes are populated from a SQL table but in this specific case, you got a point, maybe not. I modify

Comment: Is that the only code that executes in `ComboBoxUnits_SelectedIndexChanged`? Seems like changing that index updates a lot of things on your form, and that the calculation is running before `ComboBoxCostUnits.Text` updates.

Comment: @JoshuaRobinson just another line :
ComboBoxQuality Units.Text = GetStringFromQuery("SELECT qualité_unité FROM liste1 Where Nom_Unité = '" & ComboBoxUnits.Text & "'")

Comment: Is that line before or after the calculation? When you change the selected index on `ComboBoxUnits` where does `ComboBoxCostUnits.Text` get updated?

Comment: I've edited the first post with the complete code. The controls names are modified because they're written in my language but they are correct (even if you can find an error into the names). :-)

Comment: For the record, I've tried with both order (before or after the first line) and it's the same. Not working. The TextBoxTotalCost is always I scroll late

Comment: Hello there. Any idea where is my mistake ? :-)

Comment: And would it be more practical to do this in C# ? 

I'm using VB.NET because I have some old references with VB6 but I can switch to C# if everything I do is "easier"...

Answer (score 0):

Try Using

```
if(!IsPostback)
```

before the try and catch

Comment: hello Zakaria and thanks for your answer.

Well, I do not know how to syntax this in the Combobox event to be honest (VB.NET).

What would be the benefit of this ? 

Thanks.